# Meteor app - disable register

Tags: meteor

I'm using `{{> atForm}}` for login and register, and also these packages for users `accounts-password accounts-base useraccounts:unstyled`

[image]

I want to remove register possibilities for users.
It should be something in [this list](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/unstyled/tree/master/lib), but i'm not sure **what i'm supposed to override.**
Can anyone help?

---

**Edit:**
I also added this on the server,

```
AccountsTemplates.configure({
    forbidClientAccountCreation : true
})
```

and it disabled the creation of users, but i need to remove it from the UI too, like u see in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I just did this from the css :-)

```
.at-signup-link {
    display none
}
```